# Is .UtConfig folder spyware?

Tags: spyware

[image: This filejust recently popped up in my droid folder]

[image: The alvin2.xml file was in this second folder I opened]

[image: This is the first folder I opened]

I have a dozen or so new files as well. I am pretty certain the alvin file has something to do with spyware. [image][image][image][image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Exchange. Without more information on the case, it won't be possible to answer this question. Do you know which application generated these files? It's most likely an app you installed recently.

Comment: All you have here is a series of screenshots. It would be more helpful if you supplied links to external resources instead of pictures of them and a description of whatever the screenshots you do use mean.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, this folder is created by apps than contain ads created by TaoBao. Alvin2 seems to be regenerated, even if you delete it, by the same apps that create .UtConfig.

They have been existing for quite a long time and the .xml doesn't seem to cause any trouble

Comment: I just sourced it to malware...